# Transition from wood to concrete floor in middle of room

Tags: concrete, garage, subfloor, conversion

I'm converting my attached garage to a living space. The floor is graded and so will need to be raised. The deeper portion can be raised via building a wood subfloor, but the portion that's shallow doesn't leave enough depth for OSB without sticking up above the main slab. I think I can avoid this by using concrete leveler for that area (anywhere where the depth is less than ¾ in). This would mean that in the middle of the room the foundation would change from concrete to wood.

Is this a bad idea? As long as the two sections are level then I don't think flooring would have any issue, but I've also never seen it done before so I'm not sure if there are concerns that I'm missing.

The reason I'm thinking of using wood instead of raising via more concrete is that concrete can't be poured less than 2in, and leveler is crazy expensive.

Comment: The proper answer will depend on what flooring you plan on using.  If carpet or a floating floor wood to concrete would be no issue.  If you plan on ceramic tile it is almost guaranteed to crack around transition.  You could use a decoupling membrane, but that still is not 100% that you will not get cracks.